# problem with reaching attributes in xml for use in object

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm trying to put each attribute from my xml file and store each attribute in an Object, but can't reach them. What am I doing wrong? Have 2 other classes which load images too, but not important for my question.

XML:

```
<personal>
<person id="1" name="Oprah Winfrey" image="oprah-winfrey.jpg" title="administrator"></person>
<person id="2" name="Zlatan Ibrahimovic" image="zlatan-ibrahimovic.jpg" title="technician"></person>
<person id="3" name="Barack Obama" image="barack-obama.jpg" title="CEO"></person>
</personal>
```

AS3:

```
private var _items:Array = new Array();
private var _xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
private var _Loader:Loader;
private var _urlRequest:URLRequest;
private var _xml:XML;

public function Main(){
    _xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("personal.xml"));
    _xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoadComplete);
}

private function onXmlLoadComplete(e:Event):void{
    
    _xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    var _xmlList:XMLList = _xml.person;
        for each(var node in _xmlList){
            for each(var attribute in node.attributes())
            //trace(attribute.name()+"::"+attribute) //will output each attribute
            //trace("********Node End*********")
            var obj:Object = attribute;
            trace("obj "+obj.('image')); //outputs "title" node from xml file
            var item:ImageItem = new ImageItem(obj.image, 
                                            obj.name, 
                                            obj.title);
        addChild(item);

        _items.push(item);  
        }
        
    trace("items "+_items.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your very close! Here is a updated version of your loop code:

```
xml = new XML(e.target.data);

for each (var node:XML in xml.person) {
    var obj:Object = {};
    obj.name = node.@name;
    obj.image = node.@image;
    obj.title = node.@title;

    var item:ImageItem = new ImageItem(obj.image, obj.name, obj.title);

    ...
}
```

I hope that helps!